# Android Studio @Override annotation super method

Tags: android-studio, annotations

Is there any capability in Android Studio to automatically note what is the source of the @Override?

If a class implements a number of interfaces and is a subclass and one such method is

```
@Override
public void onSuccess() {}
```

it can be cumbersome or time consuming to find the source of the override.

Yes, I can right-click and select 'Go To | Super Method' but I'd rather just know where it's coming from and not change views.

Something like

```
@Override /*from OneOfManyInterfaces*/
```

would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try shorcut **ctrl + o**  and you just type what you want override

[image]

or you want customs override you can try this in kotlin
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html